# cx_freeze-4.3.4 : building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x

I am on Windows 8.1 , Python 3.5, downloaded cx_freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz, unpacked tar.gz , and modified finder.py file, and packed it back to freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz

After that, while running following command on command prompt gives error -

pip install cx_Freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz

Error :-
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Complete output is following :-

```
C:\Users\Shekhar2707\Documents\Python>pip install cx_Freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\shekhar2707\documents\python\cx_freeze-4.3.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
  Running setup.py install for cx-Freeze
    Complete output from command c:\users\shekhar2707\appdata\local\programs\pyt
hon\python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\
SHEKHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-80y2ql51-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(getat
tr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'ex
ec'))" install --record C:\Users\SHEKHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-x5fpx0qy-record
\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    adding base module named _bootlocale
    adding base module named _collections_abc
    adding base module named _compression
    adding base module named _dummy_thread
    adding base module named _frozen_importlib
    adding base module named _frozen_importlib_external
    adding base module named _strptime
    adding base module named _threading_local
    adding base module named _weakrefset
    adding base module named abc
    adding base module named argparse
    adding base module named base64
    adding base module named bz2
    adding base module named calendar
    adding base module named codecs
    adding base module named collections
    adding base module named collections.abc
    adding base module named contextlib
    adding base module named copy
    adding base module named copyreg
    adding base module named datetime
    adding base module named dummy_threading
    adding base module named encodings
    adding base module named encodings.aliases
    adding base module named encodings.ascii
    adding base module named encodings.base64_codec
    adding base module named encodings.big5
    adding base module named encodings.big5hkscs
    adding base module named encodings.bz2_codec
    adding base module named encodings.charmap
    adding base module named encodings.cp037
    adding base module named encodings.cp1006
    adding base module named encodings.cp1026
    adding base module named encodings.cp1125
    adding base module named encodings.cp1140
    adding base module named encodings.cp1250
    adding base module named encodings.cp1251
    adding base module named encodings.cp1252
    adding base module named encodings.cp1253
    adding base module named encodings.cp1254
    adding base module named encodings.cp1255
    adding base module named encodings.cp1256
    adding base module named encodings.cp1257
    adding base module named encodings.cp1258
    adding base module named encodings.cp273
    adding base module named encodings.cp424
    adding base module named encodings.cp437
    adding base module named encodings.cp500
    adding base module named encodings.cp65001
    adding base module named encodings.cp720
    adding base module named encodings.cp737
    adding base module named encodings.cp775
    adding base module named encodings.cp850
    adding base module named encodings.cp852
    adding base module named encodings.cp855
    adding base module named encodings.cp856
    adding base module named encodings.cp857
    adding base module named encodings.cp858
    adding base module named encodings.cp860
    adding base module named encodings.cp861
    adding base module named encodings.cp862
    adding base module named encodings.cp863
    adding base module named encodings.cp864
    adding base module named encodings.cp865
    adding base module named encodings.cp866
    adding base module named encodings.cp869
    adding base module named encodings.cp874
    adding base module named encodings.cp875
    adding base module named encodings.cp932
    adding base module named encodings.cp949
    adding base module named encodings.cp950
    adding base module named encodings.euc_jis_2004
    adding base module named encodings.euc_jisx0213
    adding base module named encodings.euc_jp
    adding base module named encodings.euc_kr
    adding base module named encodings.gb18030
    adding base module named encodings.gb2312
    adding base module named encodings.gbk
    adding base module named encodings.hex_codec
    adding base module named encodings.hp_roman8
    adding base module named encodings.hz
    adding base module named encodings.idna
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp_1
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp_2
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp_2004
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp_3
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_jp_ext
    adding base module named encodings.iso2022_kr
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_1
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_10
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_11
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_13
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_14
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_15
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_16
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_2
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_3
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_4
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_5
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_6
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_7
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_8
    adding base module named encodings.iso8859_9
    adding base module named encodings.johab
    adding base module named encodings.koi8_r
    adding base module named encodings.koi8_t
    adding base module named encodings.koi8_u
    adding base module named encodings.kz1048
    adding base module named encodings.latin_1
    adding base module named encodings.mac_arabic
    adding base module named encodings.mac_centeuro
    adding base module named encodings.mac_croatian
    adding base module named encodings.mac_cyrillic
    adding base module named encodings.mac_farsi
    adding base module named encodings.mac_greek
    adding base module named encodings.mac_iceland
    adding base module named encodings.mac_latin2
    adding base module named encodings.mac_roman
    adding base module named encodings.mac_romanian
    adding base module named encodings.mac_turkish
    adding base module named encodings.mbcs
    adding base module named encodings.palmos
    adding base module named encodings.ptcp154
    adding base module named encodings.punycode
    adding base module named encodings.quopri_codec
    adding base module named encodings.raw_unicode_escape
    adding base module named encodings.rot_13
    adding base module named encodings.shift_jis
    adding base module named encodings.shift_jis_2004
    adding base module named encodings.shift_jisx0213
    adding base module named encodings.tis_620
    adding base module named encodings.undefined
    adding base module named encodings.unicode_escape
    adding base module named encodings.unicode_internal
    adding base module named encodings.utf_16
    adding base module named encodings.utf_16_be
    adding base module named encodings.utf_16_le
    adding base module named encodings.utf_32
    adding base module named encodings.utf_32_be
    adding base module named encodings.utf_32_le
    adding base module named encodings.utf_7
    adding base module named encodings.utf_8
    adding base module named encodings.utf_8_sig
    adding base module named encodings.uu_codec
    adding base module named encodings.zlib_codec
    adding base module named functools
    adding base module named genericpath
    adding base module named gettext
    adding base module named heapq
    adding base module named io
    adding base module named keyword
    adding base module named linecache
    adding base module named locale
    adding base module named ntpath
    adding base module named operator
    adding base module named optparse
    adding base module named os
    adding base module named posixpath
    adding base module named quopri
    adding base module named re
    adding base module named reprlib
    adding base module named sre_compile
    adding base module named sre_constants
    adding base module named sre_parse
    adding base module named stat
    adding base module named string
    adding base module named stringprep
    adding base module named struct
    adding base module named textwrap
    adding base module named threading
    adding base module named token
    adding base module named tokenize
    adding base module named traceback
    adding base module named types
    adding base module named warnings
    adding base module named weakref
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\dist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\freezer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\hooks.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\macdist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\setupwriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\windist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\in
itscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleKeepPath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx
_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\
initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLibSource.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\initscripts
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
\samples\advanced
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\matplotlib_eg.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Free
ze\samples\matplotlib
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\PyQt4app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\sa
mples\PyQt4
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\relimport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freez
e\samples\relimport
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\Config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze
\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\ServiceHandler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\c
x_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\
samples\service
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\hello.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\s
amples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\s
amples\simple
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\
samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\SimpleTkApp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_F
reeze\samples\Tkinter
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\sampl
es\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\wxapp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\sampl
es\wx
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\samp
les\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\cx_Freeze\sam
ples\zope
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\shekhar2707\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.e
xe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SHEKHA~1\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-80y2ql51-build\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', ope
n)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record
C:\Users\SHEKHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-x5fpx0qy-record\install-record.txt --si
ngle-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\
SHEKHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-80y2ql51-build

C:\Users\Shekhar2707\Documents\Python>
```